# Is the function which calculates the volume of a rectangle an additive set function?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

A half-open rectangle is of the form $P=(a_1,b_1] \times \cdots \times (a_n,b_n]$.
Denote the collection of all half-open rectangles by $\cal P_n$.

Define a function $Vol_{0}:\cal P_n \rightarrow [0,\infty)$ by $Vol_{0}(P)=(b_{1}-a_{1})\cdots(b_{n}-a_{n})$.

A set is said to be jordan measurable if it's bounded and its boundary is zero-content. We denote the collection of all jordan measurable sets by $\cal M_n$.

A set S in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is said to **a zero-content set** if for every $\varepsilon>0$, there exists a finite number of half-open rectangles $P_1,\ldots,P_k$(for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$) such that $$P_1 \cup \cdots \cup P_k \supseteq S \quad \text{and}\quad \sum_{i=1}^{k} Vol(P_i) < \varepsilon$$

Define the following:Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^n$.
$$V^{-}(A)=sup\{\sum_{i=1}^{p} Vol_{0}(P_i) \mid P_1,\ldots,P_p \in \cal P_n, P_i \cap P_j =\emptyset for i \neq j,\bigcup_{i=1}^{p} P_i \subseteq A \}$$
$$V^{+}(A)=inf \{\sum_{j=1}^{s} Vol_{0}(Q_j) \mid Q_1,\ldots,Q_s \in \cal P_n, \bigcup_{j=1}^{s} Q_j \supseteq A \}$$

Now assume $V^{+}(A)=V^{-}(A)$=Vol(A) where $Vol: \cal M_n \rightarrow [0,\infty)$. **Prove that if $A_1,\ldots,A_k \in \cal M_n$ with $A_i \cap A_j =\emptyset$ for $i \neq j$, then $$Vol(\bigcup_{i=1}^{k} A_i)=\sum_{i=1}^k Vol(A_i)$$.**

Also, define $\mu : \cal M_n \rightarrow [0,\infty)$ to be such that $\mu(P)=Vol_{0}(P)$ for $P \in \cal P_n$ and $\mu(\bigcup_{i=1}^k A_i)=\sum_{i=1}^k \mu(A_i)$ if $A_i \cap A_k = \emptyset $ for $i \neq j$. **Prove that $\mu (A)=Vol(A)$ for $A \in \cal M_n$.**

Comment: What do you mean by "Now assume $V^+(A) = V^-(A) = Vol(A)$ where $Vol : \mathcal{M}_n \to [0, \infty)$." ? Is the statement $(\forall A \in \mathcal{M}_n) \, V^+(A) = V^-(A)$ one of the hypotheses of the problem or a part of the conclusion?

Comment: @Adayah yes it is one of the hypotheses